# Python - Insert newlines into text so text won't exceed max character width

Tags: python, email, nltk

I'm making an email in plain text. Now I have a string with text in it which I insert into the email. However, I want this text to have a max character width.

So input text is for example:

```
This is the input text. It's very boring to read because it's only an example which is used to explain my problem better. I hope you can help me.
```

And I want it to become:

```
This is the input text. It's very
boring to read because it's only
an example which is used to explain 
my problem better. I hope you can 
help me.
```

Of course we need to take into account that you can't split in the middle of a word. It may get pretty tricky when you have symols like ' and -, so I was wondering if there are tools that can do this for you? I've heard about [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) but I couldn't find a solution there yet, and maybe it's a little bit overkill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `textwrap` library for just this:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

Examples can be found there too. You likely want to use:

```
textwrap.fill(text, width)
```

Comment: A great, don't know why I couldn't find this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I now also found the preferred way to do this in a Django project (which I use). It's the built-in template tag `wordwrap`

```
{{ value|wordwrap:5 }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#wordwrap